# Error - Ruby on Rails Hartl Tutorial - Chapter 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting two errors I don't understand in Chapter 10. Have searched everywhere so really appreciate any help!

```
1) Error:
UsersSignupTest#test_valid_signup_information_with_account_activation:
NoMethodError: private method `authenticated?' called for #<User:0x00000009f0d058>
app/controllers/account_activations_controller.rb:5:in `edit'
test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:43:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'


2) Error:
UserTest#test_authenticated?_should_return_false_for_a_user_with_nil_digest:
NoMethodError: private method `authenticated?' called for #<User:0x0000000aa1f360>
test/models/user_test.rb:62:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

Account Activation Controller:

```
class AccountActivationsController < ApplicationController

def edit
user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
if user && !user.activated? && user.authenticated?(:activation, params[:id])
  user.activate
  log_in user
  flash[:success] = "Account activated!"
  redirect_to user
else
  flash[:danger] = "Invalid activation link"
  redirect_to root_url
 end
 end
end
```

The Nil digest test:

```
test "authenticated? should return false for a user with nil digest" do
assert_not @user.authenticated?(:remember, '')
end
```

From user.rb:

```
def authenticated?(attribute, token)
  digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
  return false if digest.nil?
  BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
end
```

This is my first post so sorry if it's not what it should be. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Toto

Comment: The clue is in the error message: `NoMethodError: private method 'authenticated?' called for #<User:0x00000009f0d058>`  Did you put your `authenticated?` method under the `private` declaration in the `User` class?  If so, move the method above it so it becomes `public` again.